# C++ - How to listen to a server sent event (SEE)?

Tags: c++, c++17, mql4, metatrader4

I am trying to listen to a server sent event (SEE) in C++/MQL4 natively.

Basically, through a web hook data is sent, then on the desktop I'm willing to listen to the new incoming information from the SEE.

Link:

> https://sdk.m.pipedream.net/pipelines/p_jmClnMy/sse

in JS, it's possible to do the following:

```html
const eventSource = new EventSource(
  "http://sdk.m.pipedream.net/pipelines/p_jmClnMy/sse"
);

eventSource.addEventListener("events", function(e) {
  console.log("New event from cron test event stream: ", e);
});
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found much information about doing that in C++/MQL4.